# multiple merge-from records in perforce

Tags: perforce

While building a graph of revisions in perforce, I stumbled upon several cases where a single revision is getting content from two different branches (see pic below).  How is this possible?  I didn't think integrating from multiple branches was ever an option.

Here's a sample output from filelog command:

```
> p4 filelog -m 1 //depot/xxx/xxxx/xxx/main/apps/xxxxxxx/pk/inc/xxxxx/xxxxx.h#2
//depot/xxx/xxx/xxx/main/apps/xxxx_3.1/pk/inc/xxxx/xxxx.h
... #2 change 289165 integrate on xxxx/02/09 by xxxxxxx
... ... merge from //depot/xxxxx/xxxxx/apps/xxxxxx/pk/inc/xxxx/x.h#2
... ... merge from //depot/xx/Sandbox/xxxxxxx.4.44/apps/xxxxx/pk/inc/xxxx/x.h#2
...
```

[image: p4 revision graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via P4V pretty easy. You can see X(I can't see the filename, so I'll call the bottom one X) was integrated to O, and that change was submitted.

Next right click on X say integrate/merge. It will bring up a dialog, in the "Source files/folders" add O to the list. Now in the "Source files\folders you have both X and O on 2 separate lines. Then choose ap as your "Target files/folders" then integrate it. I'm using the 2011.1 beta, but I'm pretty sure something similar was in 2010.1 as well.

Comment: I just tried taking two file revisions with a common ancestor but residing in different branches and merging them into a single revision in a third new branch.  Perforce wouldn't let me do this.  Instead of merging into a single file, it rebased everything relatively to the common base path.

Comment: What version of the client are you using? I can do a `p4 integrate -i //depot/X //depot/ap` then without resolving or submitting, `p4 integrate -i //depot/O //depot/ap` and I get a single file, with both files merging into 1(very ugly merge). Since you have a red dash, you know that the file was integrated, then checked out for edit before it was submitted, so it could have been fixed up to look right, but it's still possible.  I am using 2011.1, and like I said, should be possible with 2010.1 as well, but not 2009.2(as I found out in 1 of my test VM machines)

Comment: actually, this changelist was created back in 2006.

Comment: ah! I was able to reproduce this.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Using p4 integrate -i you can integrate between branches that have no integration history.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/integrate.html

-i: Perform the integration even if toFile and fromFile share no common ancestor, using the first revision as the base.

Comment: but there is still only a single fromFile.  So where did the other come from?